# Call WCF method from client c#

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have created one WCF service Application. There are few methods in `Service1.svc`.

Here is my **IService1.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
GetUserDetailsByEmail_Result GetUserDetailsByEmail(string email);
```

Here is my **Service.svc.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    #region GetUserDetails
    public GetUserDetailsByEmail_Result GetUserDetailsByEmail(string email)
    {
        return (new UserManager()).GetUserDetailsByEmail(email);
    }
    #endregion    
}
```

Here `GetUserDetailsByEmail_Result` is `Complex type` created in **DemoModel.edmx**. It contain some **Scalar Property**.

Basically what I am trying to do is, I want to call this method from **Client**(c#) side. Here is my **Client Side code**

```
//svc.GetUserDetailsByEmailCompleted += new EventHandler<GetUserDetailsByEmailCompletedEventArgs>(svc_GetUserDetailsByEmailCompleted);
GetUserDetailsByEmail_Result dtbUserDetails = svc.GetUserDetailsByEmailAsync(loginName);
```

Here **svc** is the object of `Service1Client`. Here I am simply calling wcf method. It gives me an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Demo.DemoServiceReference_Client.GetUserDetailsByEmail_Result'

It works when I use **svc_GetUserDetailsByEmailCompleted** method. But I want the return data directly in `dtbUserDetails`. How can I achieve this? Is there any changes in my WCF service or in my client side? Or in WCF method declaration?

Comment: I woudn't use entity framework objects as return objects, instead, create simple POCO to serve as Data Transfer Objects.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I don't know about POCO. Can you please give me any link or tutorial ?

Comment: Plain Old C-Sharp Object:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object

Comment: I use Complex Type because I am executing store procedure. I think it is easy way to get store procedure result.

Comment: I'm not talking about complex type, I'm talking about your DTOs inheriting from Entity Framework classes.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create an object and bind the data to it like some of the people in the comments suggested then mark each property like so:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "MyServiceContract.Service1.ComplexObject")]
public class ComplexObject
{
       [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
            public String DbItem1{ get; private set; }
       [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = false)]
            public ComplexBlobData DbItem2{ get; set; }
}
```

Or if you can open up the DemoModel.edmx(Code Behind) and mark it all with data contract the same way you would mark your own object.

Bottom line anything not marked is not going over the wire.